# urllib.request.urlopen() does not work for this particular website

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I have been using the following line of code in python3 to extract data from urls:

```
import urllib.request
import json
data = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen('sample-url').read().decode())
```

This works fine with all websites that I work with except this [address](https://bookit.modo.coop/api/v2/car_list). If you click on it you will see the response in json format but if you put this address in the code above it gives this error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)>
```

Comment: I used requests.get(url) and it worked, but I am still curious why urllib.request.urlopen(url) does not works.